# C# loop parallel for

Tags: c#, webforms

i have a loop to create ImageButton at runtime

```
try
        {                             
                for (int i = 0; i <= NumDia; i++)
                {
                    aImageButton[i] = new ImageButton();
                    aImageButton[i].ID = "ImageButton" + (i + 1);
                    .....
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.Controls.Add(aImageButton[i]);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }                                
            TblThumb.Rows.Add(row);
         }
```

how to transform  for (int i = 0; i <= NumDia; i++) in Parallel.For ?

i tried, aImageButton is Action parameter ?

```
 Parallel.For(0, NumDia, i =>

        {
           code
        });
```

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by parallelizing this?

Comment: Since you tagged it as WebForms, I asume you are doing ASP.Net or related development. The thing is that those and paralleizsation do nto work that well. The page lifecycle hardly supports waiting for paralell operations to return. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx Morevoer, each page request is already handeled as a paralell opeartion, so there will not be a lot of threads to go around. If you read it right, you might be stuck in a XY Problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Problem is that you can work with UI (add buttons to your row/cell) only from STA thread. But Parallel.For will create separated thread and you will got a error: System.InvalidOperationException:

```
'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'
```

Also, you can make `form.Invoke(() => row.Cells.Add(cell))` to supress this error, but you will lose all profit from `Parallel.For`, becouse `row.Cells.Add(cell)` is most expensive part of your code.

You can reproduce it with next code:

```
Parallel.For(0, NumDia, (i, state) =>
    {
        aImageButton[i] = new ImageButton();
        aImageButton[i].ID = "ImageButton" + (i + 1);
        .....
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(aImageButton[i]);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    });
```

Comment: Don't mess WebForm and WinForm.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov oops, you right. I miss it. Thanks.